# How do I get Windows Authentication Username via IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-2.0, windows-authentication

On the server, I get my current logged-in username, but from a remote client I get server name/administrator.

Below is the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  'Grab username from Windows Authentication, remove the 'HHI\', and assign to empName
  'empname = Replace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper, "HHI\", "")
  'empname = Replace(Page.User.Identity.Name, "HHI\", "")
  empname = Replace(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name, "HHI\", "")
  'empname = Replace(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, "HHI\", "")
  Response.Write(empname)
End Sub
```

I've tried Application Pools with 'Network Service', with Named Accounts and setting the pipeline mode to 'Integrated' and 'Classic'.

The above code works properly in Server 2003/IIS6, but I haven't been able to make it work on Windows Server 2008R2/IIS 7.5.

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Apparently while RDPing into the server I saved local admin permissions in my 'Credentials Vault' in Win7.  By default, these credentials overrode my network username when enumerating.

The following code is working properly:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
  'Grab username from Windows Authentication, remove the 'HHI\', and assign to empName 
  empname = Replace(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper, "HHI\", "") 
  Response.Write(empname) 
End Sub
```

Thank you for those who looked into this!